# SQL (SQLite) Madness with names

Tags: c++, sql, sqlite

I spent 2 days trying to work out a really annoying simple problem: I'm creating a database in c++:

```
sqlite3 *database;
rc = sqlite3_open(dbname, &database);

char* statement = "CREATE TABLE ONE(ID    INTEGER     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT     NOT NULL, NAME           CHAR(50)    NOT NULL, LABEL         CHAR(50), GRP             CHAR(50), FILE         BLOB        );";

rc = sqlite3_exec(database, statement, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
sqlite3_close(database);
```

Which works perfectly, checked the database structure using SQLite Studio. Now I'm trying to insert anything by executing the following statement:

```
    int rc = sqlite3_open(dbname, &database);
char *zErrMsg = 0;

char* statement = "INSERT INTO ONE(     ID,    NAME,    LABEL,    GRP,    FILE ) VALUES (     NULL,    'fedfs',    NULL,    NULL,    NULL);";

rc = sqlite3_exec(database, statement, callback, 0, &zErrMsg);


sqlite3_close(database);
```

Which keeps throwing me SQLite error 1, "no such table: ONE". The database file does open correctly. Im out of ideas.

Aside from that, I'm trying to figure out a way to open a PDF file using ifstream and store it as BLOB in SQLite. Is opening the file with ifstream the right way to store it as binary file?

Comment: Try executing `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;` and see if your table is listed in there.

Comment: It could be a permission issue? Kind of: the user you're using has permission to create tables but has no permission to insert command. I'd check user's permissions.

Comment: @Andreaoid SQLite doesn't implement such a fine-grained permission model; either you can do an update to the database, or you can't.

Comment: Is it the same database file? Could it be something obvious like that? (I've done things as daft as that in the past, so let's check for the trivial things first.)

Comment: ./facepalm. I am the dumbest person alive, the file name was missing the extention. Grattitude to Donal Fellows :)